# SSAS Cube Memory Explodes with MDX query with 10 Dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, dimensions, cube

We are querying an SSAS Cube with an mdx query that executes very quickly and efficiently with up to 9 dimensions. Once we hit 10 dimensions, cube's memory usage goes wildly out of control and uses all the available memory on the machine until it basically crashes the machine. Can anyone answer why 10 would be so radically different than 9?

```
with member measures.CatKey
    as
    [Question Answer Primary].[Q-A].currentmember.properties('key')
select {
        measures.CatKey,
        [Measures].[AverageValue],
        KPIValue('KPI Question Average Delta Wave Over Wave'),
        KPITrend('KPI Question Average Delta Wave Over Wave'),
        [Measures].[TopBoxPercent],
        KPIValue('KPI Top Box Delta Wave Over Wave'),
        KPITrend('KPI Top Box Delta Wave Over Wave'),
        [Measures].[MiddleBoxPercent],
        KPIValue('KPI Middle Box Delta Wave Over Wave'),
        KPITrend('KPI Middle Box Delta Wave Over Wave'),
        [Measures].[BottomBoxPercent],
        KPIValue('KPI Bottom Box Delta Wave Over Wave'),
        KPITrend('KPI Bottom Box Delta Wave Over Wave'),
        [Measures].[Primary Response Count]
    } on columns,

    [Question Answer Primary].[Q-A].[QUESTIONCATEGORY] * [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONKEY].[QUESTIONKEY]
    DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_VALUE on rows

from [SATPlus_Cube]

where CrossJoin({[Response Wave].[Wave].&[20110101]}, 
{
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[AfricaSpecific], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[ChinaSpecific], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[Training], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[SalesSupport], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[Relationship], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[ProductsAndPartsQuality], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[ProductSupport], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[PricingAndDiscounts],
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[Overall],
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[KeyMetrics],
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[ITSystemsSupport],
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[GovernmentNationalSales],
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[FinancingAndCredit],
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[FieldSupport], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[DistributionSupport], 
    [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[AdvertisingSupport]
}, 
NonEmpty (
        {[Sample].[SAMPLE KEY].[SAMPLE KEY]},
        ( 
            {[Hierarchy].[Node Value].&[1]}
            , [Measures].[Primary Response Count]
        )
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the subcube syntax? Maybe might works better...

```
    Select 
    {...} On Columns,
    {...} On Rows
    from (Select {{[Response Wave].[Wave].&[20110101]}} On Columns
          From {
        [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[AfricaSpecific], 
        [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[ChinaSpecific], 
        ...
        [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[DistributionSupport], 
        [Question Answer Primary].[QUESTIONCATEGORY].&[AdvertisingSupport]
    } On Columns FROM [SATPlus_Cube]))
    WHERE .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have too many members in your dimension (#10).